# Django: Does an expression like blog.user.username execute an additional database operation in django?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

Hey guys I am new to django and have a doubt regarding using these expressions a lot.
`blog.user.username` or `blog.user.email`, etc. Does this execute a database operation like we call `User.objects.get(username=blog.user.username)` to fetch that info? or is it preloaded when we load the blog instance object, i mean along with this `get_object_or_404(Blog, id=id)`?

Comment: Yes, it will make extra requests, since `ForeignKey`s, `ManyToManyField`s, etc. are loaded *lazy*: only when necessary, it will trigger an extra view. You can get the user with `blog.user` directly: this will still make a database call, but then there are two database calls, not three.

Comment: Oh..okay
Thank you for the information. I had a bad feeling since, it was pretty easy to use though. :D

Comment: If I had a onetoone relation with say profile, then, if i try to fetch this info `blog.user.profile.id`, will it be 3 database queries?

Comment: yes, although you can boost that with `.select_related`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django loads relations lazily: that means that if you load a `blog` object, it will not load `user` immediately, and thus only if you later access `.user`, it will load the user in the memory. If you for example use `blog.user.profile`, then it will make queries for `blog`, its `user` and its `profile`.

You can however boost efficiency with [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). Indeed, if we work with:

```
get_object_or_404(
    Blog.objects.select_related('user', 'user__profile'),
    pk=id
)
```

it will load the related `user` and `profile` in the *same* query, and thus this will take only one query, and the `.user` and `.user.profile` data are loaded with this database query.

Comment: Oh..okay. This looks neat. Thanks a lot!